# Split colon- and comma-separated strings in a column into different columns in R

Tags: r

```
data <- data.frame(col1 = c('0/1:60,4,4,4,4:0.044:4:0:1.00:2352,160:32:28', '0/1:58,4,4,4:0.041:4:0:1.00:2304,150:28:30', '0/1:25,2,1:0.095:1:1:0.500:908,78:9:16'))

data
                                          col1
1 0/1:60,4,4,4,4:0.044:4:0:1.00:2352,160:32:28
2   0/1:58,4,4,4:0.041:4:0:1.00:2304,150:28:30
3       0/1:25,2,1:0.095:1:1:0.500:908,78:9:16
```

Between the first and second colons, there are several numbers separated by commas. I want to know how to separate the first number and the rest into two columns.

```
data
                                          col1       col2       col3
1 0/1:60,4,4,4,4:0.044:4:0:1.00:2352,160:32:28         60    4,4,4,4
2   0/1:58,4,4,4:0.041:4:0:1.00:2304,150:28:30         58      4,4,4
3       0/1:25,2,1:0.095:1:1:0.500:908,78:9:16         25        2,1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `extract` to match characters that are not a `:` (`[:]+`) from the start (`^`) of the string followed by a `:` then capture the digits (`(\\d+)`) followed by a `,`, capture the second group of characters that doesn't include any `:` (`([^:]+)`) followed by a `:` and the rest of the characters (`.*`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
   extract(col1, into = c('col2', 'col3'),
        '^[^:]+:(\\d+),([^:]+):.*', remove = FALSE, convert = TRUE)
```

-output

```
#                                          col1 col2    col3
#1 0/1:60,4,4,4,4:0.044:4:0:1.00:2352,160:32:28   60 4,4,4,4
#2   0/1:58,4,4,4:0.041:4:0:1.00:2304,150:28:30   58   4,4,4
#3       0/1:25,2,1:0.095:1:1:0.500:908,78:9:16   25     2,1
```

---

The same regex can be used in `base R` as well with `sub` and `read.table`

```
data[c('col2', 'col3')] <-  read.table(text =
   sub("^[^:]+:(\\d+),([^:]+):.*", "\\1:\\2", data$col1), header = FALSE, sep=":")
```

---

Or use `strcapture` from `base R`

```
cbind(data, strcapture("^[^:]+:(\\d+),([^:]+):.*", data$col1, 
      data.frame(col2 = numeric(), col3 = character())))
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked well for me. But how to modify the regex if I want to extract numbers between the second and third colons.

Comment: @LinCaijin For that we can use `sub("^[^:]+:[^:]+:(\\d+):.*" "\\1", data$col1)`

Comment: Thank you. What if I want to calculate the sum of the numbers separated by comma in a cell in col3?

Comment: @LinCaijin You could do `sapply(strsplit(out$col3, ","), function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)))`

Answer (score 0):

Base R option using `sub` :

```
transform(data, col2 = sub('\\d+/\\d+:(\\d+),.*', '\\1', col1),
                col3 = sub('\\d+/\\d+:\\d+,(.*?):.*', '\\1', col1))

#.                                         col1 col2    col3
#1 0/1:60,4,4,4,4:0.044:4:0:1.00:2352,160:32:28   60 4,4,4,4
#2   0/1:58,4,4,4:0.041:4:0:1.00:2304,150:28:30   58   4,4,4
#3       0/1:25,2,1:0.095:1:1:0.500:908,78:9:16   25     2,1
```